# Remove Group Heading Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

How can I remove the heading from a grouped pivot table in Excel?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try some of the pivottable layout settings e.g. Design > layout > tabular? It would place Year to the next to Month. If you don't like the new header you can hide that row.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Image-1]

One way out is to adjust the width of the first column to make it match the other columns and then disable the ‘autofit’ feature using the pivot table options. There’s another option that you can use – simply hide them.
Click on anywhere within the pivot table. Then from the ribbon, pick up the ‘options’ tab and then click the ‘Field Headers’ button. A single click does the trick !
[image: Image-2]

The pivot table appears far neater than it did earlier and as you can see, all the columns are now equally spaced out automatically. If you need to sort or hide values, you can turn them right back on.
[image]

Comment: This is not quite what I wanted; actually I wanted to remove these "North", "South" headings.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment regarding Hakan's answer, OP has clarified that they wish to remove the Group Headings.

The structure that appears to be defined in the Question shows that the 'Month' data is being grouped by the 'Year' data -> Year (1999) is a Group, Month (Jan) is a Sub-Group of  the Year Group.

To remove the Group Headings, the 'Years' Row will need to removed from the highlighted "Rows" Field highlighted below.
As a result of doing this, only 12 rows will exist in the Pivot Table, ranging from January to December.

[PivotTable Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKSW1.png)

To clarify, the Heading Text cannot solely be deleted as this is necessary for grouping Data. Grouping is mandatory for seperating data in Pivot Tables and there's no way to remove a group without affecting the rest of the PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remove the group headings as far as I know.

What I've done before to hide them:

1. right-click the group name
2. Expand/Collapse > Collapse Entire Field
3. highlight all the heading rows
4. change the font color to white, or whatever color your group heading column is so that it appears gone
5. right-click the group name again
6. Expand/Collapse > Expand Entire Field

Now it will look something like this:
[white-out group headings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owcVF.jpg)